# Error in downloading historical weather data using R

Tags: r, data-science

I am trying to download historical weather data using 'weatherData' library in R for performing further analysis.

I used different functions in the library, but unfortunately an error is being returned saying there seems to be no data available in the URL.

I tried disabling firewall on my server, but the problem persists

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Below is the example error:

library(weatherData)

> getWeatherForDate("SEA", "2014-05-05")
>   URL to Try:
>    https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/SEA/2014/5/5/CustomHistory.html?dayend=5&monthend=5&yearend=2014&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1

Retrieving from: https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/SEA/2014/5/5/CustomHistory.html?dayend=5&monthend=5&yearend=2014&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1
URL does not seem to exist: https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/SEA/2014/5/5/CustomHistory.html?dayend=5&monthend=5&yearend=2014&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1
The original error message:
HTTP error 400.Checking Summarized Data Availability For SEA

Data is Not Available

NULL

Warning message:
In isObtainedDataValid(wxdata, station_id, custom_url) :

There seems to be no data in the URL.

Try going to the URL via your browser and seeing if there is data.

Inspect the validity of the URL being tried:
 https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/SEA/2014/5/5/CustomHistory.html?dayend=5&monthend=5&yearend=2014&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1

Comment: Hi @Jagadish, please add a minimal working example to help anyone able to assist you. This way we can recreate your error on our side.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for the information.

Comment: An always free source of weather data is NOAA, see : https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/.  You may not be able to scrap the site, but it is possible to download the data and then import it into R.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e, Unfortunately, I have limited resource on the dataset and it dates only till 2010. Would you recommend any sites for downloading recent data as well?

Comment: I agree NOAA's website is not very intuitive on how to find the desire data(your tax dollars at work).  For Seattle International airport the data is available going back to the 1940's, I suggest looking around the site to see what is available. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems to not only affect you. The site that this package provides a wrapper for apparently changed their API, thus breaking the functionality.

Check out the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Ram-N/weatherData/issues/41), where the maintainer writes:

> All, because of the change in WeatherUnderground API, where they have
>   gone to a paid model, this package no longer works. I have had to pull
>   the package off of CRAN.

Sadly, there seems to be nothing you or we can do about this. Perhaps you are able to find another site for historical weather data, one alternative is [mentioned in the issues of weatherData](https://github.com/Ram-N/weatherData/issues/40). Either you collaborate to integrate that site into `weatherData`, or you whip up a script to scrape the data you need yourself. Beware though that some sites **do not allow scraping**.

Edit:
On the other hand, if I search for the parameters you provided to the call  on weatherunderground.com, I [end up with this result](https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KBFI/date/2014-5-5?req_city=Seattle&req_state=WA&req_statename=Washington&reqdb.zip=98101&reqdb.magic=1&reqdb.wmo=99999). If only there were a way to automate a browser to conduct searches and then pull data from HTML-tables...

Edit:
[IOWA State University](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml) offers historical weather data for free download. They also provide links to community-developed scripts automating the download of their data, namely in [Python](https://github.com/akrherz/iem/blob/master/scripts/asos/iem_scraper_example.py) and in [R](https://github.com/realmiketalbot/R-scripts/blob/master/iem_scraper_example.r)

Comment: Much thanks for the information! Now that I have the reference code to scrape the data, I will try to make some changes to make the script more flexible.

Comment: @Jagadish, cool, good luck with your efforts! If this answer was helpful, I'd be thrilled if you mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I can download the dataset, but I am getting per every hour from the start date until the end date which I think is unnecessary. Is there any way to download monthly data rather than hourly data?

Comment: @Jagadish, are you referring to the wunderground-data? Because on the page I linked, at the top you have a "slider" that allows you to choose between daily, weekly, and monthly data. Does that help? I wasn't able to find anything comparable for the NCDC data

Comment: Not on the wunderground-data, but on the dataset of IOWA State university. I am trying to remove the '&day' section in the R code ( I am modifying R code for time consumption ) that must be provided along with the URL (variable name : 'service' in the code), but the dataset would not even download. If I could somehow get only the annual monthly data for different years, that would be more than helpful! :) Or is there any other URL that you can suggest for scrapping the data?

Comment: @Jagadish, why don't you hard-code that field to always be 1, i.e. the first of every month, and then send repeating queries iterating through the months and years? However, be aware that this puts stress on the (free of charge!) API, as it can more efficiently serve a range of dates for you. I suggest you grab the data it provides and do the filtering yourself. In the intro on top of that page, they mention a [Python](https://github.com/akrherz/iem/blob/master/scripts/asos/iem_scraper_example.py) and an [R script](https://github.com/realmiketalbot/R-scripts/blob/master/iem_scraper_example.r)

Comment: Tried it that way. Unfortunately it does work either. Somehow it happens to download only for hourly data no matter what changes you make in the script.